# Open Java programs of a linux machine on Windows with SSH?

Tags: linux, ssh, windows, java, xforwarding

I usually use laptop (which has Windows) to ssh to my Linux server and run stuff on it (e.g. Intellij, MATLAB).

I wonder if there anyway to open Java programs (again, like Intellij) of a remote linux machine, in Windows environment (say by doing something like Xforwarding?), since both machines already contain JVM.

Note that I don't want to run the programs directly on Windows (since they have some dependencies on my linux server). So instead I need to run it on linux. The desired is a way to open the such "java" programs (which are running on a remote unix machine) in the Windows environment (like how people use Xforwarding when ssh-ing between linux machines).

Note: I have been using FastX and NXClient so far, but these are too slow and annoying.

Comment: It *should* work just fine directly in Windows. After all, isn't that the slogan of Java: "write once, run anywhere"? I'm not a Java person, so I could be wrong; however I thought the JIT compiler enabled you to do that.

Comment: I don't want to run it on Windows, instead I want to run it on linux, but use it in Windows environment (like how people use Xforwarding). I am clarifying this in the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use X forwarding on Windows as well; all you need is an X server (such as [Xming](http://www.straightrunning.com/XmingNotes/)) and an SSH client (such as [PuTTY](http://www.putty.org/)). Xming includes documentation explaining how to go about things; basically, you enable X forwarding in PuTTY, start the X server on your Windows machine, SSH to the Linux machine and run your Java application. You might find that rather slow though.

Alternatively you might get better results with VNC; you need to start a VNC server on the Linux machine and connect to it with a VNC client on the Windows machine. You'll find VNC servers packaged for your Linux distribution; a decent VNC client for Windows is [TightVNC](http://www.tightvnc.com/download.php).

Comment: In addition to this, the solution I like is moba: https://mobaxterm.mobatek.net.